# Different coil turns

Tags: ac, dc, coil

Why there is a different number of turns? Why there is not 8 turns on each side?

[image: picture of schematic]

Comment: Because 6 is all that is needed to switch the gate. It's not like a push-pull driver which would be symmetrical.

Comment: So if I need 400V, there will be the same ratio? 5:3?

Answer (score 2):

> Why there is not 8 turns on each side?

Because 6 is all that is needed to switch the gate. It's not like a push-pull driver which would be symmetrical.

> So if I need 400V, there will be the same ratio? 5:3?

Yes. If you want to change the output voltage then change the number of turns on the secondary. Reduce to 4/5 = 80% of the turns required for 500 V.

I would not expect good voltage accuracy or stability from such a simple circuit.

Comment: I'd honestly be surprised if this didn't at random points experience breakdowns across the 1N4007, if that 500V is actually achieved... there's not much headroom to breakdown voltage.